# How can I size the Sankey Chart Starting blocks?

Tags: javascript, css, sankey-diagram

I am trying to figure out how I can custom size the individual Sankey Chart starting blocks?

For example I would like the coal vertical starting line along with the pathway to be a percentage smaller than the Natural Gas vertical starting line. I have tried looking at Google Development Documents, But I only see reference as to how to expand, spread out, and change the color of the Sankey Diagram.

[image]

Here is my current code via JSFiddle:

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addRows([
      [ 'Nuclear Electric Power', 'Electricity Retail Sales', 100 ],
      [ 'Renewable Energy', 'Electricity System Energy Losses', 29 ],
      [ 'Coal', 'Electricity System Energy Losses', 96 ],
      [ 'Natural Gas', 'Electricity System Energy Losses', 44 ],
      [ 'Petroleum', 'Transportation', 87 ],
      [ 'Electricity System Energy Losses', 'Commercial', 69 ],
      [ 'Electricity System Energy Losses', 'Residential', 69 ],
      [ 'Electricity System Energy Losses', 'Industrial', 28 ],
      [ 'Renewable Energy', 'Commercial', 1 ],
      [ 'Renewable Energy', 'Residential', 8 ],
      [ 'Renewable Energy', 'Industrial', 61 ],
      [ 'Coal', 'Industrial', 4 ],
      [ 'Natural Gas', 'Commercial', 12],
      [ 'Natural Gas', 'Residential', 13],
      [ 'Natural Gas', 'Industrial', 30],
      [ 'Natural Gas', 'Transportation', 1],
      [ 'Petroleum', 'Commercial', 2 ],
      [ 'Petroleum', 'Residential', 2 ],
      [ 'Petroleum', 'Industrial', 9 ]
      //MAKE SURE TO NOT PUT A COMMA ON THE LAST BLOCK
    ]);

    // Sets chart options.
   var options = {
     width: 600,
    };


//var options = {
  //height: 400,
  //sankey: {
    //node: {
      //colors: colors
    //},
    //link: {
      //colorMode: 'gradient',
      //colors: colors
    //}
  //}
//};

    // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical line for coal (the rectangle is known as a Node) is sized based on the value/weight in your data.  If you look at Coal it has a combined value or 100 ([ 'Coal', 'Electricity System Energy Losses', 96 ] + [ 'Coal', 'Industrial', 4 ]).  Decrease the value from 96 to 50 (example) and the Node height changes.  Hope this helps.